# Swiper JS CSS not Importing into Laravel 8

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-8, swiper.js

I was using the Swiper.js CDN on a Laravel 8 project and just installed it with NPM. For some reason, the CSS is not importing (the javascript is working fine).

I've tried importing it a few different ways, but I'm not sure why it's not importing. This is what I have currently in my main.css

**main.css**

```
@import "~swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try to remove `~` and edit like this `import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on `docs` all you need is to remove `~`

```
@import 'swiper/swiper-bundle.css'
```

for more info check the installation guide [here](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#install-from-npm)